# XSL to extract epub-metadata

Tags: xml, xslt, epub

I want to extract existing metadata from opf-files of epub-books with xsl.

Example of opf-file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" unique-identifier="db-id" version="3.0">

<metadata>
    <dc:title id="t1">TITLE</dc:title>
    <dc:identifier id="db-id">ISBNUUID</dc:identifier>
    <dc:creator id="creator">CREATOR</dc:creator>
    <dc:language>LANGUAGE</dc:language>
    <meta property="dcterms:modified">DATETIME</meta>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
</metadata>

<manifest>
    <item id="toc" properties="nav" href="toc.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item id="ncx" href="toc.ncx" media-type="application/x-dtbncx+xml" />
    <item id="template_css" href="template.css" media-type="text/css" />
    <item id="hello" href="1_hello.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
</manifest>

<spine toc="ncx">
    <itemref idref="hello" />
</spine>

</package>
```

I need to extract pairs `<nodename>: <nodevalue>` like this:

```
title: TITLE
identifier: ISBNUUID
...
```

But it seems like even can't to address this nodes properly. And I'm not shure about namespaces..

My xsl now looks like this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="metadata">
    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Xmlstarlet produces only node-values and alot of empty strings:

```
$ xmlstarlet tr select-opds-metadata.xsl ../s3opdsd/epubgen/var/epub-boilerplate/OEBPS/content.opf


    TITLE
    ISBNUUID
    CREATOR
    LANGUAGE
    DATETIME
    en

... truncated ...
```

I hope anyone can help with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistakes:

1. You are not taking into account the source XML's namespaces.
2. You are processing the `metadata` element, instead of its children.
3. You want punctuation, but you're not specifying any.

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:o="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" >
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/o:package">
    <xsl:for-each select="o:metadata/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael! Your answer is a subject for my self-education now